# Showing Drop Off on Google Sankey Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to use a Google Sankey Chart to show how many players played a quiz, completed it, and won or lost it. I have the following code:

```
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','sankey']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        //console.log(gameAssets);
        
        function drawChart() { 
                    var sankeydata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    sankeydata.addColumn('string', 'From');
                    sankeydata.addColumn('string', 'To');
                    sankeydata.addColumn('number', "Number of Players");
                    sankeydata.addRows([
                      [ "Number of Players","Completions", 391 ],
                      ["Completions","Successful Completions",160],
                      ["Number of Players","Exit" ,768],
                      ["Completions","Unsuccessful Completions",231]
                    ]);
        
                    // Sets chart options.
                    var options = {
                      width: 970,
                      sankey: {
                        node: {
                          width: 4 ,
                          colors: ['#883b90'],
                          label: { 
                             fontSize: 14
                               
                          }
                        },
                        link: {
                          color: { fill: '#f4eee2' }
                        }
                      }
                    };
                    var sankey_chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
                    sankey_chart.draw(sankeydata, options)
    }
        
               
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <div id="sankey_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

The problem I am having is that the players that don't complete the quiz (shown as "Exit" on the Sankey Chart) are on the last column (the same column as Successful Completion and Unsuccessful Completion). I'd rather have it at the same level as the Completions. 
Even a better option, showing a drop off like in google Analytics with a red arrow pointing down like the one below:

[image: Google Analytics Drop off]

Is it possible using Google Charts?

Comment: Good question. Upvote and bookmark.
There is similar question for `react-vis` Sankey too but no solution unfortunately https://github.com/uber/react-vis/issues/35

Comment: One more also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619778/can-i-control-order-of-links-in-a-sankey-diagram-of-react-vis

Comment: Faced the same questions. Drop offs are really necessary, but can't find a way to add them.